# 3 steps + confirmation MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to design a Game creation controller/view process in which

the user will have STEP 1: CREATE GAME then hits submit to move to STEP 2: choose a location then to STEP 3 invite friends and confirm the creation of the website.

- data should not be commited to the database until the user clicks the final confirm button

how can I do that using ASP.NET MVC 4 (I am currently using EF5 and have all my models correctly generated and so on.

- should I submit back to the server after every step and ask for the second view to be displayed or is there any other mecanism to handle this kind of design ?

thanks a lot for your feedback

Comment: If you don't want anything done on Db until the last step, ASP.NET MVC4/Entity Framework are irrelevant at this point. Your concern is Javascript.

Comment: This question is opinion based in that it will depend on the style of implementation. You can use ajax and the user will never navigate thus holding the information client side. Or you can store the information in a session so that the user can post from page to page. Or you can have a temporary staging area in a db table to hold the information as the user moves through the process. etc.

Comment: going along with @James comment http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: I would save it to db, because you can use it to generate statistics (i.e number of users that started but not finish registration process)

Answer (score 2):

It would be easiest to use the Session and GET/POST requests. See this overly simple example:

```
class SignupController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult CreateGame()
    {
        // render the view
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult CreateGame(Game model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // store "model" in session
            return RedirectToAction("location");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("edit", model);
        }
    }

    public ViewResult Location()
    {
        // render the view
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult Location(int id, Location location)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            RedirectToAction("...")
        }
        else
        {
            return View("edit", location);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was a quick down-vote :)